# Apply function to each cell in a row, based on another cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have the following:

| . | a | b | benchmark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 3 |

and I would like to apply a condition in Pandas for each column as:

```
def f(x):
  if x > benchmark:
    # X being the values of a or b
    return x
  else:
    return 0
```

But I don't know how to do that. If I did `df.apply(f)` I can't access other cells in the row as `x` is just the value of the one cell.

I don't want to create a new column either. I want to directly change the value of the cell as I compare it to benchmark, clearing or 0'ing the cells that that do not meet the benchmark.

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function, instead use vectorial operations:

```
out = df.where(df.gt(df['benchmark'], axis=0), 0)
```

To change the values in place:

```
df[df.le(df['benchmark'], axis=0)] = 0
```

Output:

```
   a  b  benchmark
0  0  2          0
1  0  5          0
```

If you don't want to affect `benchmark`:

```
m = df.le(df['benchmark'], axis=0)
m['benchmark'] = False

df[m] = 0
```

Output:

```
   a  b  benchmark
0  0  2          1
1  0  5          3
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked for my case. If I had to do something more complex in future operations, how do I adapt this for use with a function? @mozway

Comment: can the function be vectorized?

Comment: let's assume "yes" while I go look up how to vectorize a function ... LOL

Comment: Maybe update the question with an example (or open a new question if the logic is too different)

Comment: I will ask again when I have a specific example then. Thank you1